# with Python is there a way to listen for changes when insert or update is made in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, mod-wsgi, pymongo, uwsgi

I am building a small system which throws data from a mongodb collection, it already works fine but I have to restart it everytime I make changes.
I already have a monitor that dectect changes and restarts the server automatically but I want to do something like this with mongodb changes.
I am currenlty using CentOs 5, Nginx, uWsgi & python2.7.

Comment: You have to google for triggers and MongoDB. It is a feature request and you can find some recipes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd look into using [tailable cursors](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tailable+Cursors), which remain alive after they've reached the end of a collection, and can block until a new object is available.

Using [PyMongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find), you can call `Collection.find` with a `tailable=True` option to enable this behavior. This [blog post](http://shtylman.com/post/the-tail-of-mongodb/) gives some good examples of its usage.

Additionally, instead of just querying the collection, which will only alert you to new objects *added* to that collection, you may want to query the database's *oplog*, which is a collection of all insert, updates, and deletes called on any collection in the database. Note that replication must be enabled for mongo to keep an oplog. Check out this [blog post](http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2010/10/12/replication-internals/) for info about the oplog and enabling replication.